# Using PHP two dimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

in php I have this array

```
$MAtoJS[] = array('Max','Mustermann','N','A80');
$MAtoJS[] = array('Michaela','May','N','A78');
$MAtoJS[] = array('Hans','Gerstelhuber','N','M12');
$MAtoJS[] = array('Alfred E.','Neumann','N','T25');
$MAtoJS[] = array('James','Bond','N','M72');
```

Still in the php part I prepare the array for js

```
$MAarrayForJS = json_encode(json_encode($MAForJS));
```

In the javascript part I create a js-array

```
var MAarray = new Array(<?php echo $MAarrayForJS; ?>); alert(MAarray)
```

The content of MAarray is

```
[["Max","Mustermann","N","A80"],["Michaela","May","N","A78"],["Hans","Gerstelhuber","N","M12"],["Alfred E.","Neumann","N","T25"],["James","Bond","N","M72"]]
```

using

```
console.log(MAarray[0]);
```

I tried to get for example the first name of Hans by this code

```
var FirstName = MAarray[0][2][1];
```

which results in "undefined" in the console.log.

How can I access to a specific value in a specific array, in this case to set the var FirstName to the value "Hans" from the third "subarray"?

Comment: Notice the different between `$MAForJS` and `$MAtoJS` (probably just typo). And you may need `MAarray[2][0];`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this... ?

```
$MAtoJS = [];

$MAtoJS[] = array('Max','Mustermann','N','A80');
$MAtoJS[] = array('Michaela','May','N','A78');
$MAtoJS[] = array('Hans','Gerstelhuber','N','M12');
$MAtoJS[] = array('Alfred E.','Neumann','N','T25');
$MAtoJS[] = array('James','Bond','N','M72');

$MAarrayForJS = json_encode($MAtoJS);

?>

<script>
    var MAarray = <?php echo $MAarrayForJS; ?>;
    console.log(MAarray[0][0]); // Max
</script>
```

Comment: Thats the correct way! JSON is valid JavaScript, no need to parse it really.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the array is **2 dimensional** and not **3 dimensional** you're accessing the 3rd dimension which will always yield undefined, have a look at below code snippet in which the value is fetched, altered as per the requirement:

```js
let MAarray = [["Max","Mustermann","N","A80"],["Michaela","May","N","A78"],["Hans","Gerstelhuber","N","M12"],["Alfred E.","Neumann","N","T25"],["James","Bond","N","M72"]];

console.log(MAarray[2][0]);

MAarray[2][0] = "New Name";

console.log(MAarray[2][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are using json_encode 2 times. You only need to use it once.

Change following

```
$MAarrayForJS = json_encode(json_encode($MAForJS));
```

To

```
$MAarrayForJS = json_encode($MAtoJS);
```

Then in the JS you can use console.log(MAarray[0][2][1]);

Comment: Ok, thanks. Works now as wanted. The reason is "google" - how to determine which search result is right? And there were many with double json_encode.

Comment: I have never used double json_encode and neither came across a reason to do so. No way to determine which google result is correct, just need to play around the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var FirstName = MAarray[2][1];
```

It seems like you are trying to access the third level of a two dimensional array.